# Getting array from object in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Input-
{
    "0": {
        "NAME": "ABC"
    },
    "1": {
        "NAME": "DEF"
    },
    "2": {
        "NAME": "GHI"
    },
    "3": {
        "NAME": "JKL"
    },
    "4": {
        "NAME": "MNO"
    }
}
```

I have this input. I want to get only names in array format like this Output-

```
["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"].
```

try

```
var arr =[]; for( var i in data ) { if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)){ arr.push(data[i]); } }
```

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Parse the object and iterate

Comment: I was trying like this @AmeyaDeshpande
var arr =[];
for( var i in data ) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                arr.push(data[i]);
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the keys of the `object` and map its `NAME` property into an array.

```js
var input = { "0": { "NAME": "ABC" }, "1": { "NAME": "DEF" }, "2": { "NAME": "GHI" }, "3": { "NAME": "JKL" }, "4": { "NAME": "MNO" } };

var result = Object.keys(input).map(function(key){
 return input[key].NAME;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop over object and get values.

#### Object.keys + Array.map

```js
var data={0:{NAME:"ABC"},1:{NAME:"DEF"},2:{NAME:"GHI"},3:{NAME:"JKL"},4:{NAME:"MNO"}};

var result = Object.keys(data).map(x=>data[x].NAME)
console.log(result)
```

#### for..in

```js
var data={0:{NAME:"ABC"},1:{NAME:"DEF"},2:{NAME:"GHI"},3:{NAME:"JKL"},4:{NAME:"MNO"}};

var result = [];
for(var key in data){
  result.push(data[key].NAME)
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the keys are numeric, or can easily be converted to a number, if you add a length property then you can utilize the built in array iteration methods. You could then use the reduce method to build your array.

Here is an ES6 example:

```js
const input={0:{NAME:"ABC"},1:{NAME:"DEF"},2:{NAME:"GHI"},3:{NAME:"JKL"},4:{NAME:"MNO"}};

input.length = Object.keys(input).length;

const result = Array.prototype.reduce.call(input, 
    (output, element, index) => ((output[+index] = element.NAME), output), []);

console.log(result); // ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var result={0:{NAME:"name1"},1:{NAME:"name2"},2:{NAME:"name3"}};
var array = [];

for(var i=0; i<=result.length-1; i++){
  array.push(result[i].NAME);
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Please use `for..in` on objects. `for` will not work as `result` is a single object and does not have a property length. Also, please add explanation to your answer. Just adding code is not good enough